Problems with payments using Stripe for iOS
I'm developing an app for iOS and Android that uses Stripe as its payment platform. On Android (Google Play), everything works perfectly and the payment process runs smoothly. However, I'm having problems publishing the app on the App Store.
Here's the situation:

When I test the app in the Xcode emulator or on real devices with the development version, payment via Stripe works correctly.
However, when I put the app into production on the App Store, the payment simply doesn't work. The app crashes when trying to process the payment, and the payment page doesn't load.

What I've already checked:

Testing vs. Production Mode:

The payment on Android and in the tests on the Xcode emulator is working, so the integrations with Stripe seem correct.


SSL Certificates and Permissions:

I checked the network permissions in Info.plist to ensure that communication between the app and Stripe is taking place correctly in production.
SSL certificates are configured correctly on the server and are valid.


Logs and debugging:

I can't reproduce the problem in the development environment, only in production.
In the Xcode logs, no specific payment-related error appears, but the payment page simply won't load in production.



Questions:

Is there any additional configuration required when using Stripe specifically for the App Store that I might be overlooking?
Do I need to make any adjustments to my implementation to ensure it complies with Apple's policies?
Is there anything specific about the network communication between the app and Stripe that could work in the emulator but fail in production?

I appreciate any help or suggestions that can guide me to solve this problem! If you need more details, I can provide specific code or logs.

You'll probably need to write in to Stripe's Support for help on this: https://support.stripe.com/contact
